# Can't able to apply Bounds Control in Prefab

Tags: hololens, windows-mixed-reality, hololens-emulator

I'm using prefab instead of objects. I'm able to apply **bounds control's handle style (Hololens 2 style)** in Objects But not in prefab which I've created.
Is there any solutions, How can I apply Hololens2's Handle style in prefab ?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajjtM.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save the Configuration in **BoundsControl/Visuals** as an .asset file for reuse in the prefab. You can also drag the .asset file from **Packages/Mixed Reality Toolkit Foundation/SDK/StandardAssets/Profile/BoundsControl/HoloLens2Style_Slate** to the Assets folder, modify it to the style you want, and then add it to the **BoundsControl** component of the prefab.